# Ionic 3 not applying default style to button

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I've started a blank project with Ionic 3 and the default style is not applying to the buttons.

I'm using a default button with

```
<button ion-button>Prueba</button>
```

But I get this

[image]

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

Using

```
<ion-button block color="primary">Acceder</ion-button>
```

Fix the problem but I notice that is not using full width in the div than contains the button

```
<div padding>
   <ion-button block color="primary">Acceder</ion-button>
</div>
```

Not sure where is the problem

Comment: are you sure you are using ionic 3? maybe 4...?

Comment: Ups! You're right. I'm using 4.0.0-beta.12. I was looking at the wrong documentation

Comment: cool yo:) glad to help